# Unable to do bulk indexing for large file in elasticsearch

Tags: java, python, elasticsearch

I am trying to do bulk indexing in elasticsearch using Python for a big file (~800MB). However, everytime I try

> [2016-01-08 15:06:49,354][WARN ][http.netty               ] [Marvel Man] Caught exception while handling client http tra
>   ffic, closing connection [id: 0x2d26baec, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58923 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9200]
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: HTTP content length exceeded 104857600 bytes.
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:169)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeli
>   ne.java:791)
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:135)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeli
>   ne.java:791)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeli
>   ne.java:791)
>           at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:75)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Can anyone please help me understand what is happening here, and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: I guess it clearly says `org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: HTTP content length exceeded 104857600 bytes`. Your file is too big.

Comment: see this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2137), error is clearly saying your file is huge, you have to split it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increase the content uploading length which is by default 100mb.
Go to **elasticsearch.yml** in **config** folder

add/update -

> http.max_content_length: 300M